# How to escape characters in Handlebars

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, escaping, handlebars.js

I have "name" variable in the view and I want to display something like this in the rendered HTML:

```
${Jon}
```

Right now, my code is like this:

```
<li>
  {{name}}
</li>
```

I am storing `name` in the view directly as `"${" + model.name + "}"`. But I dont want to store names this way, I want to display the characters `$`, `{` and `}` in the handlebars template.

How to you escape { and } in the handlebars to be normal strings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the HTML ASCII code:

```
&#123; = '{'
&#125; = '}'
```

example:

```
<li>&#123;{{item}}&#125;</li>
```

if `item = 'apple'`, then this becomes:

> {apple}

[JSBin example](http://jsbin.com/analac/2/edit)