# Escaping curly brackets standing next to expression in handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.java

Can't understand how to escape { or } symbols standing next to expression at [handlebars java templating engine](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java).

I'm using handlebars templates to generate plain text so I can't use HTML ASCII codes of braces as advised [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16271795/how-to-escape-characters-in-handlebars).

I need expression like `\{{{variable.name}}\}` to be resolved to `{variable.value}`. Should I create helpers for that or there is a cleaner way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some examples of escaping. The last method escape with a helper (when the other methods are not possible).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var context = {
    "textexample1" : "hello",
    "textexample2" : "<div><b>hello</b></div>",
    "textexample3" : "{ 'json' : 'sample }"
  };
  Handlebars.registerHelper('surroundWithCurlyBraces', function(text) {
    var result = '{' + text + '}';
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(result);
  });
 var source   = $("#sourceTemplate").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  var html    = template(context);
  $("#resultPlaceholder").html(html);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script id="sourceTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
Simple text : {{textexample1}}<br/>
Html text not escaped : {{textexample2}}<br/>
Html text escaped : {{{textexample2}}}<br/>
Json text : {{textexample3}}<br/>
Non JSON text with surrounding mustaches {} : { {{textexample1}} }<br/>
Non JSON text with surrounding mustaches (no space)  : &#123;{{textexample1}}&#125;<br/>
Solution with helper : {{#surroundWithCurlyBraces textexample1}}{{/surroundWithCurlyBraces}}
</script>
<br/>
<div id="resultPlaceholder">
</div>
```

Comment: I can't add space or other character between surrounding mustashes and double brackets. Template should be resolved as {variable.value} exactly

Comment: I've added a solution for you : use the html code for {} (&#123; and &#125;). The answer was updated accordingly

Comment: I can't use HTML ASCII. I specified it in question. This is plain text generator so no other rendering after template resolved.

Comment: Then the only solution I see is to build a helper that will add your curly braces around the computed text. Do you need the code ?

Comment: I've updated the answer again with a solution that uses a helper.

Comment: Thanks! I already have a solution with helper but it look like overhead for me. Still looking for a simplier solution. No easy way to escape symbol in template is disappointment

Comment: See my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035670, it includes an ugly but working way of inserting `{` and `}` without an additional helper.

Answer (score 2):

```
{{myvar}}{{append '' '}'}}
```

append helpers from here:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/handlebars-helpers#string

Comment: Ugly as hell but works.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Managed to make it work with a hack like this:
{{ curlyOpen }}{{ variable.name }}{{ curlyClose }}
Where you should define additional variables curlyOpen="{" and curlyClose="}" as part of your context.

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this.

In the end, adding a helper function was the easiest solution.

I enhanced the solution suggested by @Christophe since I also needed the camelCase version of the given parameter:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('surroundWithCurlyBraces', function(text, camelCase) {
  
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(surroundWithCurlyBraces(camelCase? _.camelCase(text): text));
});
```

Then you can call it as follows:

```
{{surroundWithCurlyBraces variable.name}}
```

or - if you need camelCase

```
{{surroundWithCurlyBraces variable.name true}}
```