# Literal braces in Handlebars template

Tags: handlebars.js, handlebars.java

I'm having difficulties including braces `{` `}` in a Handlebars template so that it didn't interfere with Handlebars syntax.

Specifically, I want to have a template like this:

```
{{{sometag}}}
```

Except that I want the first and the last braces to be rendered literally, rather than be a part of Handlebar's "non-escaped expression" syntax.

For now, the shortest portable syntax I could come up with is `{{#with "{"}}{{.}}{{/with}}`, so that the template that I want would look like:

```
{{#with "{"}}{{.}}{{/with}}{{sometag}}{{#with "}"}}{{.}}{{/with}}
```

I could use HTML entities (like https://stackoverflow.com/a/16278085/3088208 suggests), or insert an HTML comment after the initial `{` and before the final `}`, but these solutions, while practical, depend on HTML which makes them limited.

P. S. Found a duplicate question: [Escaping curly brackets standing next to expression in handlebars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52020784)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `{ {{~sometag~}} }`? As I understand the "specification" and your question, it should do what you want: The outer braces are single and will be quoted verbatim, but the adjacent white space should be removed because of the tildes.

Comment: Nice and short, thank you! And it works perfectly with Java Handlebars implementation that I use (even though I already don't remember the use case that I had for this). Marking as answer.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who lands here in the future, this solution worked for me [Render double curly-brackets inside handlebars partial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22249235/render-double-curly-brackets-inside-handlebars-partial)

TL;DR Add a `\` to your value eg `\{{{whatever}}}` will render `{{{whatever}}}`

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I would test it, but I no longer remember where I needed it. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was also searching for this solution and couldn't find anything. So I've created helper

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('bracket', function(num, options = num) {
 const i = Number.isInteger(num) ? num : 1;
 const open = '{'.repeat(i);
 const close = '}'.repeat(i);
 return `${open}${options.fn(this)}${close}`;
});
```

You can use it like

```
{{#bracket 2}}styles.{{name}}{{/bracket}}
```

it will give

```
{{styles.Name}}
```

If number of brackets was not specified it will be one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but using a helper adds a dependency that I want to avoid if I can. (If I wanted to go with a helper solution, I would define an inline helper to be used like this: `{{literal '{'}}{{sometag}}{{literal '}'}}`